# Custom cell editor in slick grid not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, slickgrid

I implemented a slick grid with custom cell editor and rendered the grid in dialog popup.
When I click the cell the custom cell editor opens and works perfectly.
But when I close the dialog cell editor not gets closed and it retains in another page.
Also the cell editor not get closed when I clicked outside the grid.
Also I tried the below code but it is not suited for all condition.

```
var editController = grid.getEditController();
editController.commitCurrentEdit();
```

Any body please give a nice solution to close the cell editor when I do any operation out side the grid.

Comment: are you destroying the grid when the dialog is closed?

Comment: @BenMcIntyre If I destroyed the editor means I need to reinitialize it whenever the dialog gets opened is it. This way is also OK for me. But is there any default method to close the editor when the parent dialog closes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
grid.getEditorLock().cancelCurrentEdit();
```